# How load data from DB and create widgets automaticaly and how delete a widget and remove from DB?

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy, kivy-language

I am beginner and start studing with python kivy and sqlite3, and I stuck in this two points:

1 - I am have some troubles to get the text value from the label id: txtLabel from widget Item and then remove from database tarefas.db
I don't know what I missing here, I tryed in different ways get the txtLabel text but I always get some error...

2 - When the app run I want to automaticaly create the widgets Item with the names registered in database tarefas.db
I tryed using a for statement, but nothing happens...

Below are the file codes:

#PYTHON FILE - main.py#

```
import kivy
kivy.require("2.0.0")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import sqlite3

class app_db(App):
    def build(self):
        # CREATE A DB TABLE IF NOT EXIST
        con = sqlite3.connect("tarefas.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tarefas(
            name text
        )""")
        con.commit()
        con.close()

        return Builder.load_file("interface.kv")

        # LOAD DATA AND CREATE ITEM WIDGETS
        con = sqlite3.connect("tarefas.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM tarefas")
        records = c.fetchall()

        for record in records:
            self.root.ids.box.add_widget(Item(texto=record))

        con.commit()
        con.close()



    def addItem(self):
        txt = self.root.ids.txtInput.text

        con = sqlite3.connect("tarefas.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO tarefas VALUES(:txt)",
                  {"txt": txt})
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM tarefas")
        records = c.fetchall()

        for record in records:
            print(record)

        con.commit()
        con.close()

        self.root.ids.box.add_widget(Item(texto=txt))

    def delItem(self):
        txt = self.app.txtLabel.text

        con = sqlite3.connect("tarefas.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("DELETE FROM tarefas WHERE name = (?)", (txt,))
        con.commit()
        con.close()

        print("executou")

class Item(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, texto=""):
        super().__init__()
        self.ids.txtLabel.text = texto




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_db().run()
```

#KV FILE - interface.kv#

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: "Adicionar"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        on_release: app.addItem()
    TextInput:
        id: txtInput
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        GridLayout:
            id: box
            cols: 1
            spacing: 5
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

<Item>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 60
    Button:
        text: "-"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 50
        on_release: app.delItem()
        on_release: app.root.ids.box.remove_widget(root)
    Label:
        id: txtLabel
```

Comment: When you run your kivy App it just shown a black screen?

Comment: When I run the kivy app appears the widgets Button, TextInput and the black area of GridLayouyt

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to load data and create the widget Item automaticaly for every record when the kivy app is initialized, it was necessary add a function called **on_start** inside of **class app_db(App)**:

```
# LOAD DATABASE AND CREATE WIDGETS ITEM
def on_start(self):
    # Connect to database
    con = sqlite3.connect("tarefas.db")
    c = con.cursor()
    # Select all records
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM tarefas")
    records = c.fetchall()
    # Create a widget Item for every record
    for record in records:
        self.root.ids.box.add_widget(Item(texto="%s" %record))
    # Close database conection
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

For be able to remove a record from database I had to move de function **delItem()** to inside of **class Item(BoxLayout)**:

```
    # DELETE RECORD FROM DATABASE
    def delItem(self):
        txt = self.ids.txtLabel.text
        # Connect to database and delete a record
        con = sqlite3.connect("tarefas.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("DELETE FROM tarefas WHERE name = (?)", (txt,))
        # Print actual database records
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM tarefas")
        records = c.fetchall()
        print("-----------")
        for record in records:
            print(record)
        # Close database conection
        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

The full **main.py** code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("2.0.0")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import sqlite3

class app_db(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("interface.kv")
        # CREATE A DATABASE TABLE IF NOT EXIST
        con = sqlite3.connect("tarefas.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tarefas(
            name text
        )""")
        con.commit()
        con.close()

    # LOAD DATABASE AND CREATE WIDGETS ITEM
    def on_start(self):
        # Connect to database
        con = sqlite3.connect("tarefas.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        # Select all records
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM tarefas")
        records = c.fetchall()
        # Create a widget Item for every record
        for record in records:
            self.root.ids.box.add_widget(Item(texto="%s" %record))
        # Close database conection
        con.commit()
        con.close()

    # ADD A NEW ITEM
    def addItem(self):
        txt = self.root.ids.txtInput.text
        # Connect to database and insert a record
        con = sqlite3.connect("tarefas.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO tarefas VALUES(:txt)",
                  {"txt": txt})
        # Print actual database records
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM tarefas")
        records = c.fetchall()
        print("-----------")
        for record in records:
            print(record)
        # Close database conection
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        # Add widget Item to GridLayout
        self.root.ids.box.add_widget(Item(texto=txt))
        self.root.ids.txtInput.text = ""

# CLASS OF WIDGET ITEM
class Item(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, texto=""):
        super().__init__()
        self.ids.txtLabel.text = texto

    # DELETE RECORD FROM DATABASE
    def delItem(self):
        txt = self.ids.txtLabel.text
        # Connect to database and delete a record
        con = sqlite3.connect("tarefas.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("DELETE FROM tarefas WHERE name = (?)", (txt,))
        # Print actual database records
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM tarefas")
        records = c.fetchall()
        print("-----------")
        for record in records:
            print(record)
        # Close database conection
        con.commit()
        con.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_db().run()
```

The full **interface.kv** file:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: "Adicionar"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        on_release: app.addItem()
    TextInput:
        id: txtInput
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        GridLayout:
            id: box
            cols: 1
            spacing: 5
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

<Item>:
    id: item
    orientation: "horizontal"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 60
    Button:
        text: "-"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 50
        on_release: root.delItem()
        on_release: app.root.ids.box.remove_widget(root)
    Label:
        id: txtLabel
```

After those implementations, if you add some Item widgets and close the kivy app when you run the kivy app again all data will be altomatically loaded and the widgets will be created.

Comment: The code had a little mistake, it will only works if the database is already created, if don't, you will receive an error, to correct that is just put the **CREATE A DATABASE TABLE IF NOT EXIST** inside of **on_start** function